# Swift MacOs - Accessibility - AxError: cannot complete

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

I'm trying to create a fuction, that will return selected text in any application. For that purpose I'm using Accessibiliy API, and my function looks like:

```
func getSelectedText() -> String? {
    // Get the currently active application
    guard let frontmostApplication = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication,
        let runningApplication = NSRunningApplication(processIdentifier: frontmostApplication.processIdentifier) else {
            return nil
    }

    // Get the AXUIElement for the application
    let applicationElement = AXUIElementCreateApplication(frontmostApplication.processIdentifier)

    var focusedElement: CFTypeRef?
    let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
        applicationElement,
        kAXSelectedTextAttribute as CFString,
        &focusedElement
    )
    // !!! result = AxError: cannotComplete !!!
    if result != .success {
       return nil
    }

    let focusedUIElement = focusedElement as! AXUIElement

    // Get the selected text
    var selectedText: AnyObject?
    let selectedTextResult = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedUIElement, kAXSelectedTextAttribute as CFString, &selectedText)

    if selectedTextResult == .success, let selectedText = selectedText as? String {
        return selectedText
    } else {
        // Try getting the value of the focused element instead
        var value: AnyObject?
        let valueResult = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedUIElement, kAXValueAttribute as CFString, &value)

        if valueResult == .success, let value = value as? String {
            return value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting AxError: cannot compete on the following line:

```
let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
    applicationElement,
    kAXSelectedTextAttribute as CFString,
    &focusedElement
)
```

App Sandbox is enabled, accessibility is also granted for this app in OS, not sure is there any other reason to fail like that?

**EDIT**

When I try to request permission using the following:

```
let prompt = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String
let options: NSDictionary = [prompt: true]
let appHasPermission = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
```

`appHasPermission` param is false

Comment: Do you call `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions`?

Comment: You are trying to get the selected text from the selected text from the frontmost application. Get the selected text from the focussed element from the frontmost application instead.

Comment: hey Willeke! can you please advice me on how to use AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions? I've tried to use focussed element too, but still same error. I'm getting this for all element access from frontmost application :[

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions

Comment: just tried as described in the EDIT section, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Accessibility API isn't available for sandboxed apps. You should turn the sandboxing off.