# Accessibility issue: AXIsProcessTrusted() returns false on TestFlight release (debug/release builds are ok)

Tags: swift, macos

Even if Accessibility is [trusted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS6nL.png) function `AXIsProcessTrusted()` returns false on **TestFlight release**

### This behaviour can be reproduced ONLY on TestFlight release

(In local debug and release builds all works well)

What can be reason?

upd: tried another way with same results:

```
fileprivate func checkIsTrusted() -> Bool {
    let prompt = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String
    let options: NSDictionary = [prompt: true]
    let appHasPermission = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
    
    return AXIsProcessTrusted() || appHasPermission
}
```

[PC restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348641/axisprocesstrustedwithoptions-doesnt-return-true-even-when-the-app-is-ticked-in) also din't help

Environment information:

- Xcode: Version 14.2 (14C18)
- MacOs: Ventura 13.1 (22C65)
- Build type: TestFlight release (local debug and release versions works well, issue in TestFlight release only)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Similar question: [Swift MacOs - Accessibility - AxError: cannot complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75054454/swift-macos-accessibility-axerror-cannot-complete)

Comment: Were u able to solve this?

Comment: @kkyr I didn't solve this as I have found that Accessibility isn't needed for my app in case of use another functions